# Problema al instalar angular-cesium en Angular 6

Tags: angular

Estoy tratando de instalar [Angular-cesium](https://github.com/TGFTech/angular-cesium) en un proyecto generado con [Ngx-rocket](https://github.com/ngx-rocket/generator-ngx-rocket) y obtengo este error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Intente generar el proyecto con ng-cli y el mismo error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intenta colocar lo siguiente en tu tsconfig.json

```
"noImplicitAny":false
```

Te recomiendo dar una mirada a la [documentacion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html)